# errors when using get and set of ArrayList to put object from a position of ArrayList to a position in another ArrayList

Tags: android, collections, arraylist

any reason for there to be a problem for using get and set of the ArrayList collections class like this,  I am getting runtime errors

want to put the Prize object at y position in one `ArrayList` "**oneList**" to the y postion of another `ArrayList` called "**rungame**"

```
 ArrayList<Prize> xrt = new ArrayList<Prize>();
 ArrayList<Prize> rungame = new ArrayList<Prize>();

 for(int y = 0; y < xrt.size(); y++){

  rungame.set(y, xrt.get(y));

 }
```

**Logcat output:**

```
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:477)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at lottery.MainLottery.onClick(MainLottery.java:231)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14110)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-29 16:16:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2644):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You are getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. because there is no Object in position 'y' within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is with `rungame.set();` method you are accessing an empty ArrayList and setting the data in the **specified index** which it wont has.

means in first iteration `rungame` has 0 element and you are trying to set `Prize` object in 0th index which it wont have.

try to use `rungame.add(xrt.get(y));` and refer the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: thank you,  it works now!!!   my error was the "set" in  rungame.set(y, xrt.get(y)); and your fix works perfectly, rungame.add(xrt.get(y))